# Index out of range while executing results from db

Tags: python, sqlite, execute, indexing

I'm having a problem while trying to simply execute data from rows from db (sqlite3). The DB input has 4 fields, therefore once entered they're being saved. But here's my problem, where I execute all of the 4 rows, if one of the fields was not filled I get an error.

That's the database execute code:

```
def ids(self):
    con = lite.connect('foo.db')

    with con:

        cur = con.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT Id FROM foo")

    while True:

        ids = cur.fetchall()

        if ids == None:
            continue

        return ids
```

And since there are 4 rows, my output code:

```
 print ''.join(ids[0]) + ',' + ''.join(ids[1]) + ',' + ''.join(ids[2])
 + ',' + ''.join(ids[3])
```

so my question is how to make an exception when there's no existing row to not show anything and just leave the ones that actually exist? I tried doing `if ids[0] is not None: #do something` but that would make my code really slow and it's non-pythonic way I guess. Is there any better way to make that work? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the 'output code' with respect to the other code? Immediately below it?

Comment: The output code is not below it, it's above it. Does it matter though ? The ids as a function is below the output, but I might change it if it matters.

Comment: Why the `while True`? There is no need to retry the `fetchall` call.

Comment: Just `return cur.fetchall()` will do fine.

Comment: Can you put the full code in the example? I'm i see that your variable name and function name or the same, just wondering if there are some namespace issues here.

Comment: What is that `while True` loop supposed to do? If `cur.fetchall()` ever returned `None` (which it shouldn't), I'd expect that it would return `None` again the next time you call it, so you'd just spin in an infinite loop forever.

Comment: Also, if you want to limit things to 4 rows, instead of selecting everything, and then fetching all of the rows, and then only using the first 4, you should probably add `LIMIT 4` to the query and/or just fetch the first 4 rows out of the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have 4 rows. Make it generic and just join an arbitrary number of rows:

```
ids = someobject.ids()
print ','.join(''.join(row) for row in ids)
```

You can simplify your database query, there is no need to 'poll' the query:

```
def ids(self):
    with lite.connect('foo.db') as con:
        cur = con.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT Id FROM foo")
        return cur.fetchall()
```

You could also just loop directly over the cursor, the database will handle buffering as you fetch:

```
def ids(self):
    with lite.connect('foo.db') as con:
        cur = con.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT Id FROM foo")
        return cur   # just the cursor, no fetching

ids = someobject.ids()
# this'll loop over the cursor, which yields rows as required
print ','.join(''.join(row) for row in ids)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll try it in a sec. Was thinking of something like this to be honest, hope it works.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you! I did your third example and it works perfect now! Thanks again man